# Insert data in multiple tables if a checkbox is checked

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am creating a user registration form with simple requirements.and insert data with simple query

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["form_register"]))
{
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO users SET
                        users.first_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']) . "',
                        users.last_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']) . "',
                        users.email='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "',
                        users.password='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "';";

    if (mysql_query($insert_query))
    {
        $_SESSION['messageType'] = "success_msg";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "-Registration not Successful.";
        $_SESSION['messageType'] = "error_msg";
    }
}
?>
```

but now I have 3 extra fields in this form. If I select a checkbox then the other 2 field data go in another table with having this data also. how can i do that?

It is my old code...now I add 3 new columns, 1 checkbox and 2 text boxes.

The query is, if checkbox is selected then other 2 colums values go in another table and if checkbox is not select then working 1 query.

Comment: Please review your posted code, it seems like missing some parts.

Comment: Please give the snippet of your form.

Comment: @ravinath=>"but now I have 3 extra field in this form If I select a checkbox then other 2 field data go in another table with having this data also". what does this mean? please explain

Answer (score 0):

We really need to see your form as what you're providing us is way too vague, also, check the ending syntax for your `$insert_query`.

If I comprehended the question right, the final code should look something like this.

Tell me if I'm wrong

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST) && isset ($_POST["form_register"])){
    $insert_query1 = "INSERT INTO users SET
        first_name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname'])."',
        last_name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname'])."',
        email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."',
        password='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'";

    if(mysql_query($insert_query)){
        $_SESSION['messageType'] = "success_msg";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message']  = "-Registration not Successful.";
        $_SESSION['messageType'] = "error_msg";
    }

    if($_POST['checkbox']) {
        $insert_query2 = ""; //Put your second MYSQL Query here
    }

    if(mysql_query($insert_query2)){
        $_SESSION['messageType2'] = "success_msg";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message2']  = "-Registration not Successful.";
        $_SESSION['messageType2'] = "error_msg";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: he cant comment at the moment as he dont have enough reputation so i guess he is answering it instead of commenting.

Comment: Now he posted a real answer, before not. I'll change my vote.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough rep to post a comment, so I posted an outline, hoping OP would see it, then add the code later

Comment: can I check form this if($_POST['checkbox']) a checkbox is select or not?

Comment: `if($_POST['checkbox'])` basically means if the form element with `name="checkbox"`, in this case, a checkbox, is selected, the `if` will be true

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you want to insert data in another table IF user check the checkbox.

So you have to use another IF like this:

```
if (mysql_query($insert_query))
{
    if (/* here your condition for checkbox*/)
    {
        /* here your query for the secund table and the new two values*/
    }

    $_SESSION['messageType'] = "success_msg";
}
```

Note that is extremely important you run the secund query **after** the **success** of the first, cause if the first fails for some reason, secund will not be executed.